# Serializing/marshalling package level user define record types to JSON

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, oracle19c

I'm trying to convert a record type, defined in a PL/SQL package, to JSON.

I found that in SQL, I can use `select json_object(*) from SomeTable`, to return objects that have a property for each column in the table, but I can't seem to do this with record types in PL/SQL code.

Example package with types and a function to return (serialize) json based on a type:

```
create or replace package Customer as
  type RT_Address is record (
    Line1 varchar2(100),
    Line2 varchar2(100),
    City varchar2(100)
  );

  type RT_Customer is record (
    FirstName varchar2(100),
    LastName varchar2(100),
    Address RT_Address
  );

  function AsJson(P_Customer RT_Customer)
  return varchar2;

end;

create or replace package body devvanessa.Customer as

  function AsJson(P_Customer RT_Customer)
  return varchar2 is
    V_DOM jdom_t;
    V_JSON json_object_t;
    V_JSONBody varchar2(4000);
  begin

    V_JSON := json_object(P_Customer); -- PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol when expecting one of the following: . ( * @ % & - + / at mod remainder rem <een exponent (**)> || multiset value

    if V_DOM.append(P_CUSTOMER) then -- PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments
      null;
    end if;
    V_JSONBody := V_Json.STRINGIFY;

    return V_JSONBody;
  end;

end;
```

The above is slightly simplified, because I actually want to store this json and do some other things with it, but it does show the core of my problem:

How do I convert a record type to Json in PL/SQL, without specifying all individual fields separately.
I'm also curious how it would work the other way around.

I've been searching various sources, like [documentation on JSON functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/JSON_VALUE.html#GUID-C7F19D36-1E75-4CB2-AE67-ADFBAD23CBC2), [Oracle 19's JSON documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/overview-of-pl-sql-object-types-for-json.html#GUID-A22995AD-A144-4A5C-AB80-A17225A56E41), and simply the code completion hints I got on the `json_object_t` and `jdom_t` types, but so far I can't find any evidence that it's possible at all.

This would work:

```
    V_JSon.Put('FirstName', P_Customer.FirstName);
    -- repeated for each property
```

This way I get json, but it requires me to specify each field individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON_OBJECT_T does not have a constructor that takes in a record type so you will need to explicitly define each of the keys/values to define the JSON.  JDOM_T is not required for what you are attempting to do.  Below is an example on how to convert your record types to JSON and back.

```
DECLARE
    TYPE RT_Address IS RECORD
    (
        Line1    VARCHAR2 (100),
        Line2    VARCHAR2 (100),
        City     VARCHAR2 (100)
    );

    TYPE RT_Customer IS RECORD
    (
        FirstName    VARCHAR2 (100),
        LastName     VARCHAR2 (100),
        Address      RT_Address
    );

    l_customer1   rt_customer
        := rt_customer ('John', 'Doe', rt_address ('123 Main Street', 'Apartment# 2A', 'London'));
    l_customer2   rt_customer
        := rt_customer ('Jane', 'Smith', rt_address ('456 Broken Dreams Blvd', NULL, 'Greenville'));
    l_json        json_object_t;
    l_record      rt_customer;

    FUNCTION customer_record_to_json (P_Customer RT_Customer)
        RETURN json_object_t
    IS
        l_address    json_object_t := json_object_t ();
        l_customer   json_object_t := json_object_t ();
    BEGIN
        l_address.put ('Line1', p_customer.address.line1);
        l_address.put ('Line2', p_customer.address.line2);
        l_address.put ('City', p_customer.address.city);

        l_customer.put ('FirstName', p_customer.firstname);
        l_customer.put ('LastName', p_customer.lastname);
        l_customer.put ('Address', l_address);

        RETURN l_customer;
    END;

    FUNCTION customer_json_to_record (p_customer_json json_object_t)
        RETURN rt_customer
    IS
        l_address_json   json_object_t := json_object_t ();

        l_address        rt_address;
        l_customer       rt_customer;
    BEGIN
        l_address_json := p_customer_json.get_object ('Address');
        l_address.line1 := l_address_json.get_string ('Line1');
        l_address.line2 := l_address_json.get_string ('Line2');
        l_address.city := l_address_json.get_string ('City');

        l_customer.firstname := p_customer_json.get_string ('FirstName');
        l_customer.lastname := p_customer_json.get_string ('LastName');
        l_customer.address := l_address;
        RETURN l_customer;
    END;
BEGIN
    l_json := customer_record_to_json (l_customer1);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Customer 1 (JSON): ' || l_json.stringify);
    l_record := customer_json_to_record (l_json);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Customer 1 (Record) (FirstName): ' || l_record.firstname);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Customer 1 (Record) (LastName): ' || l_record.lastname);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Customer 1 (Record) (Line1): ' || l_record.address.line1);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Customer 1 (Record) (Line2): ' || l_record.address.line2);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Customer 1 (Record) (City): ' || l_record.address.city);

    l_json := customer_record_to_json (l_customer2);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Customer 2 (JSON): ' || l_json.stringify);
    l_record := customer_json_to_record (l_json);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Customer 2 (Record) (FirstName): ' || l_record.firstname);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Customer 2 (Record) (LastName): ' || l_record.lastname);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Customer 2 (Record) (Line1): ' || l_record.address.line1);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Customer 2 (Record) (Line2): ' || l_record.address.line2);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Customer 2 (Record) (City): ' || l_record.address.city);
END;
```

### Update

It is possible to just `JSON_OBJECT(*)` to create a JSON object, but the * expansion will not work with record types as you will get a `ORA-40579: star expansion is not allowed`.

If you do wish to use `JSON_OBJECT` to create the JSON instead of JSON_OBJECT_T, the types you are using will need to be predefined (not in the pl/sql block) and you will still need to define each field in the JSON structure.  You will also need to define a table type of the RT_CUSTOMER type so that you can query from it.

```
CREATE TYPE RT_Address AS OBJECT (Line1 VARCHAR2 (100), Line2 VARCHAR2 (100), City VARCHAR2 (100));

CREATE TYPE RT_Customer AS OBJECT
(
    FirstName VARCHAR2 (100),
    LastName VARCHAR2 (100),
    Address RT_Address
);

CREATE TYPE rt_customer_t AS TABLE OF rt_customer;

SELECT json_object (
           'firstname' VALUE firstname,
           'lastname' VALUE lastname,
           'address' VALUE
               json_object ('line1' VALUE TREAT (address AS rt_address).line1,
                            'line2' VALUE TREAT (address AS rt_address).line2,
                            'city' VALUE TREAT (address AS rt_address).city)) as customer
  FROM TABLE (
           rt_customer_t (
               RT_Customer ('John',
                            'Doe',
                            rt_address ('123 Main Street', 'Apartment# 2A', 'London')),
               RT_Customer ('Jane',
                            'Smith',
                            rt_address ('456 Broken Dreams Blvd', NULL, 'Greenville'))));
```

Comment: Thanks! Not what I wanted to hear, but I'm afraid it's all there is.. :o)